# create jquery element from ajax html response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax function which return a html. It looks like:

```
<div class="item">
    <h1></h1>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h1></h1>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h1></h1>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I am trying display them by [grid-a-licious](http://bestofjquery.com/layout/grid-a-licious/) jquery grid plugin. According examples when I want to append them I need to create array of divs with class 'item'. So I tryed this code:

```
function createItems(data) {
    var items = new Array;
    $('.item', data).html().each(function() {
        items.push($(this));
    });
    return items;
}
```

But html code is going into console with Error: syntax error unrecognized expression
Where is a problem?

Comment: On which line is the syntax error?

Comment: @AlexMorrise line 3 where he's using `"".each(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use .each on a string. Secondly, your selector is not returning any elements because `.item` is a top level element in `data`.

```
function createItems(data) {
    var items = [];
    $(data).each(function() {
        items.push(this);
    });
    return items;
}

$(createItems(somedata)).doSomething();
```

or even

```
function createItems(data) {
    return $(data).map(function() {
        return this;
    }).get();
}

$(createItems(somedata)).doSomething();
```

or

```
$(somedata).doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just return

```
function createItems(data) {
    return $(data);
}
```